# Extract All File Names from a .rar or .zip File in Node.js

Tags: node.js, file, zip, rar, busboy

I have an `express` route, that uploads files, that are sent to the server via `formData`.

Supposing the file is a `.rar` or `.zip` file, my goal is to extract all file names, that is inside this zipped folder or it's subfolders.

This is how my `express` route currently looks like:

```
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers })
        busboy.on('finish', async () => {
            const fileData = req.files.file
            console.log(fileData)
            // upload file
            // send back response
        })
        req.pipe(busboy)
    } catch (err) { return response.error(req, res, err, 'uploadProductFile_unexpected') }
}
```

Here is what the `console.log(fileData)` looks like:

```
{
    data:
        <Buffer 52 61 72 21 1a 07 01 00 56 0c 22 93 0c 01 05 08 00 07 01 01 8d d6 8d 80 00 85 76 33 e4 49 02 03 0b fc d4 0d 04 b1 8c 1e 20 bc 86 da 2e 80 13
    00 2b 66 ... >,
    name: 'filename.rar',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
    truncated: false,
    size: 224136
}
```

Inside `filename.rar` are a few files like `texture.png` and `info.txt`. And my goal is to fetch those names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the .files function available using JSZip.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var JSZip = require("jszip");

// read a zip file
fs.readFile("project.zip", function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    JSZip.loadAsync(data).then(function (zip) {
      files = Object.keys(zip.files);
      console.log(files);
    });
});
```

is an example of one such solution, courtesy of [this tutorial.](https://www.codediesel.com/nodejs/how-to-read-and-create-zip-files-in-nodejs/) You should be able to use a similar function on your file from the `req` request.

Comment: That's working great with `.zip` files. However `.rar` files throw an error

Comment: Hmm, makes sense. You could try using unrar and handing them separately based on the file extension. https://www.npmjs.com/package/unrar

Comment: I also thought about that, but it seems that this package is quite unpopular. Is it save to use?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [NodeJS File System](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html) API. Explicitly [fs.write](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback) that takes the buffer as an argument. So once you have the `fileData` object, you can do something like

```
fs.write(fileData.name, fileData.data, (err) => {
/* handle errors and results*/
});
```